# Can each Firefox tab have its own keyboard layout / language?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-layout, firefox-extensions, browser-tabs, input-languages

In Internet Explorer, when I switch my keyboard language in a tab, it doesn't affect other tabs that are already open (i.e., they retain their original kbd languages). Can I achieve the same in Firefox? Currently, when I switch the keyboard language in FF, it changes in all tabs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please have a look at [TabLang](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tablang/).

> Allows you to keep separate keyboard layout for each tab and
>   automatically changes system input locale when switching between tabs
>   or windows - the feature Firefox lacks in comparison with Internet
>   Explorer.
>
> Features:
>
> - Changing keyboard layout when switching between tabs/windows (including sidebars)
> - Configurable default keyboard layout for new tabs/windows
> - Opening link in new tab/window preserves keyboard layout
> - Preserving independent keyboard layout for address bar globally or on pre-tab basis
> - Preserving independent keyboard layout for web search bar and page find bar
> - Session restore support
> - Undo close tab, tab drag-n-drop and tear-off support
> - Panorama (tab grouping) support

[image]

Comment: available only on windows.

Comment: for Linux available  too, Debian Stable XFCE4

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned addons don't work anymore for the benefit of others who come this way. After months of searching I finally found something that works on all browsers. It is not an extension or addon it is a windows background app and thus has access to the needed functionality:

https://github.com/AlexVallat/KeyLayoutAutoSwitch/releases/tag/v2.0-alpha

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.